# How to show log screen on Android?

Tags: android, user-interface, debugging, logging

During development, we often need to see all console logs on screen. Build a UI component (Android) that shows logs on screen so you can debug while running code on the phone.

I have a question like that and I couldn't think of a solution. How can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

Use one of this libraries:

[Lynx](https://github.com/pedrovgs/Lynx)

[Logcat Viewer](https://github.com/fatangare/LogcatViewer)

[Debug Overlay](https://github.com/sockeqwe/debugoverlay)

[Galgo](https://github.com/inaka/galgo)